# RODBC-Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?

Tags: sql, r, sql-update, rodbc

I have two tables in my database called "COL" and "Duplicates".  I want a to change a value in the field "item_price" in COL to the value in the field "avg_price" in Duplicates if the values in the field "generic" match in both tables.  My code is:

```
library(RODBC)
db <- "C:/Projects/Online.accdb"
col <- odbcConnectAccess2007(db) 
sql=paste0("update COL set COL.item_price=Duplicates.avg_price where COL.generic=Duplicates.generic")
result <- sqlQuery(col,sql)
close(col)
```

But I get the error

> [1] "07002 -3010 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few
>   parameters. Expected 2."
>   [2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'update COL set
>   COL.item_price=Duplicates.avg_price where
>   COL.generic=Duplicates.generic'"

I thought this was pretty simple, but I can see I'm wrong.

Comment: Is "_" a special character in Access? You may want to try putting brackets around your variable names: `"update COL set COL.[item_price]=Duplicates.[avg_price] where COL.generic=Duplicates.generic"`.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it.  It's something about the Two few parameters statement, but I can't figure out what it is since this query has worked on single items, but now I want it to go through the entire table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your SQL query never sources in *Duplicates* table. Therefore, the engine does not know what the alias means. Simply adjust for an `UPDATE ... JOIN` query where the `WHERE` clause becomes a `JOIN` clause:

```sql
UPDATE COL c
INNER JOIN Duplicates d ON c.generic = d.generic
SET c.item_price = d.avg_price;
```